# Adding an email address to my Outlook mobile app will give the Office 365 admin ability to access my mobile phone?

Tags: iphone, microsoft, ms-office

I work as a freelancer for many companies. For each company, they create an Office 365 account for me. To manage those emails, I am planning to download Outlook mobile app on my iPhone and add all those accounts, so I have a single app to manage all the emails.

If I add an account to my Outlook mobile app, will this allow the Office 365 admin to access my iPhone files and photos?

In other words, will they have access to my iPhone?

Comment: @schroeder mobile phones are off topic at [su]. It might be better to be migrated to [apple.se] judging by the iPhone tag.

Comment: @Mokubai apologies. I was unaware. Since this is ultimately a question about this particular app, I'm unsure that it fits on Ask Different, either. Do we have a site that deals with end-user questions around apps?

Comment: @schroeder  Not really, but the question is broadly "can an app on my iPhone give someone remote access" which is a question that depends on the phone security model and application together. It's an Apple device so to me it is one for the [apple.se] crowd, though it likely already has been asked there in some form or another.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks for the clarfications